# Hex conversion of GUID removes Zeros?

Tags: powershell, hex, guid

I have a script that takes the hex value of a GUID and converts to a GUID. However it is removing zeros for eg. this is my output. And the reg reads for the hex values.

```
$GUIDLocal1 = (Get-ItemProperty "$Reg\Common Api")."UniqueID"
$GUIDLocal2 = (Get-ItemProperty "$Reg\Test\Common Api")."UniqueID"

# This is not code below just info
$GUIDLocal1 is 54 171 225 63 61 204 14 79 168 61 49 246 193 140 121 152
$GUIdlocal2 is 54 171 225 63 61 204 14 79 168 61 49 246 193 140 121 152
ID in Database is              36ABE13F3DCC0E4FA83D31F6C18C7998
$guidinhex                     36ABE13F3DCCE4FA83D31F6C18C7998
$guidinhex2                    36ABE13F3DCCE4FA83D31F6C18C7998
# This is not code above just info
```

I am using this code for the conversion

```
$guidinHex = [string]::Empty
$guidinHex2 = [string]::Empty
$GUIDLocal1 | % { $guidInHEX += '{0:X}' -f [int]$_ }
$GUIDLocal2 | % { $guidInHEX2 += '{0:X}' -f [int]$_ }
```

ID is GUID with all `{`, `}`, and `-` removed for ease of view.
`$GUIDLocal1` and `$GUIDLocal2` is the hex value in registry.

I then use the code above to convert (`$GUIDLocal1` and `$GUIDLocal2` is the values guidinhex / 2).

The conversion works, but if there is a zero it strips it out as you can see above - this machine the GUID actually matches the reg values but my conversion is skewing the result I just need to know why and how not to have the conversion remove the Zero / s.

I thought adding `[int]` would help but to no avail.

Comment: `"{0:X2}" -f 0` outputs `00`, `"{0:X2}" -f 1` outputs `01`, etc.

Comment: That did the trick thanks!

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question.

Comment: Sorry how can i mark Bill_Stewart as correct

Comment: Comments aren't answers and thus can't be accepted.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart should write up a quick answer explaining the string format notation that he used, which you could then accept as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` (format) operator lets you format a numeric value as a hexadecimal string with leading zeros. The format specification is `{0:Xn}` or `{0:xn}`, where *n* is the number of digits desired in the string output (padded with zeros if needed). Uppercase `X` or lowercase `x` specifies whether you want the hex values `A` through `F` to be uppercase or lowercase. Examples:

```
"{0:X2}" -f 15   # outputs string 0F
"{0:X3}" -f 27   # outputs string 01B
"{0:x4}" -f 254  # outputs string 00fe
```

...and so forth. Documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString